# How to configure x509 client certificate based authentication to connect to AWS RDS based PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, security, ssl, x509

We want to enforce encryption-in-motion for connecting to our PostgreSQL database hosted in Amazon AWS RDS. We followed the steps given here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL

After doing the steps we are able to connect to the database with a command given below where we are using the root certificate provided by AWS:

```
    psql -h mydb.ckpjohsjh7j8.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 "dbname=mydb user=root password=mypassword sslrootcert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem sslmode=verify-full"
```

However, we are also able to connect without specifying the "sslrootcert" or "sslmode" parameters as seen in command below:

```
    psql -h mydb.ckpjohsjh7j8.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 "dbname=mydb user=root password=mypassword"
```

This means that x509 client certificate validation is not enabled for AWS RDS. I suppose there must be some way to generate my own private key and csr to get a public key signed by AWS or some way to configure customer provided private, public key. I searched the AWS documentation but could not locate any reference on how to enable it.

Could you please guide me on how to configure "enforcement" of x509 client certificate based authentication to connect to AWS RDS based PostgreSQL database?

Kind regards,
Shashi

Comment: *"This means that x509 client certificate validation is not enabled for AWS RDS."*  Client certificate validation is indeed not enabled, but your test doesn't actually prove that.  What you are doing is only disabling authentication of the server's certificate by the client.

Answer (score 8):

We contacted AWS support and got confirmation that RDS currently does not support configuring user generated, provided private on database server that could be used with corresponding signed public key. It's in their product backlog.

Comment: For the record, we just reached out to AWS support about this (specifically about Aurora 3 MySQL 8), and they said "After conducting a thorough investigation and consulting our internal team, it has been determined that RDS/Aurora does not support logging in via certificates." They instead steered us to Kerberos authentication or IAM authentication.